# Issue with SELECT MAX CASE

Tags: mysql, case

In my db I have operations and milestones that affects them. I need to valuate an operation milestone type  which is a text field, and then get the max value and its id according to that value. Lets suppose operation.id = 1 to simplify.

In the milestones table I have

```
id | type   | operation_id
1  | 'Ori'  | 1
2  | 'Lib'  | 1
3  | 'Desc' | 1
```

I tried:

```
SELECT m.id,
MAX(CASE
    WHEN m.type = 'Ori'   THEN 0
    WHEN m.type = 'Trans' THEN 1
    WHEN m.type = 'Arriv' THEN 2
    WHEN m.type = 'Ofic'  THEN 3
    WHEN m.type = 'Lib'   THEN 4
    WHEN m.type = 'Ret'   THEN 5
    WHEN m.type = 'Desc'  THEN 6
    WHEN m.type = 'Dev'   THEN 7
END) val
FROM milestone m WHERE m.operation_id = 1
```

What I expected to get:

```
id | val
3  | 6
```

What i got:

```
id | val
1  | 6
```

If I add to my query: GROUP BY m.id

I get:

```
id | val
1  | 0
2  | 4
3  | 6
```

I know I can order this by val and then limit the result to 1 but it's not what I want.

Comment: "but it's not what I want" - Why not? It looks like that.

Comment: This is a VERY simplified version of the real query, in fact, this is a part of a subquery in a bigger query, limit the number of results won't let me do other things I need.

Comment: Then post a less simplified version.

Comment: For any non-aggregated, non-grouped field, you will get "some value" that occurred in the group; so with no grouping at all, you just get some value from the rows that were aggregated (not eliminated by a join or where condition). In many other RDBMS, and the default configuration of more recent versions of MySQL, that query is not even allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM milestone m 
WHERE m.operation_id = 1
ORDER BY 
  (CASE
    WHEN m.type = 'Ori'   THEN 0
    WHEN m.type = 'Trans' THEN 1
    WHEN m.type = 'Arriv' THEN 2
    WHEN m.type = 'Ofic'  THEN 3
    WHEN m.type = 'Lib'   THEN 4
    WHEN m.type = 'Ret'   THEN 5
    WHEN m.type = 'Desc'  THEN 6
    WHEN m.type = 'Dev'   THEN 7
  END) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @LPena https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep the `type` and its `value` in a separate table (TypeValue) or a temporary table, so it will be easy to join with milestone table to get the expected result:

```
CREATE TABLE milestone (id integer, `type` varchar (5), operation_id integer);

INSERT INTO milestone (id, `type`, operation_id) VALUES
(1, 'Ori', 1),
(2, 'Lib', 1),
(3, 'Desc', 1);

CREATE TABLE TypeValue (`type` varchar (5), value integer);

INSERT INTO TypeValue ( `type`, value) VALUES
('Ori'  , 0),
('Trans', 1),
('Arriv', 2),
('Ofic' , 3),
('Lib'  , 4),
('Ret'  , 5),
('Desc' , 6),
('Dev'  , 7);
```

The working query is:

```
SELECT m.id, t.value
FROM milestone m 
JOIN TypeValue t on t.`type` = m.`type`
WHERE m.operation_id = 1
ORDER BY t.value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

```
id  | value 
------------
3   | 6
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=544117fee9b8ac8fc9947b577f02e3f9)

Comment: If it is helped to solve your problem, please consider to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this without creating a separate table, using LIMIT, or sorting, you could use an inline table (table subquery).

To be honest, you would be better off putting the value list in a separate table like Arulkumar did and then storing that associated value in your milestone table.

This works by matching each milestone id with its type value as a subquery and then matching the results with another subquery that returns the overall max type value for the operation_id.

```
Select * From
(SELECT m.id, 
    CASE
        WHEN m.type = 'Ori'   THEN 0
        WHEN m.type = 'Trans' THEN 1
        WHEN m.type = 'Arriv' THEN 2
        WHEN m.type = 'Ofic'  THEN 3
        WHEN m.type = 'Lib'   THEN 4
        WHEN m.type = 'Ret'   THEN 5
        WHEN m.type = 'Desc'  THEN 6
        WHEN m.type = 'Dev'   THEN 7
    END val
FROM milestone m) inlineTable
Where val = 
(Select Max(CASE
    WHEN type = 'Ori'   THEN 0
    WHEN type = 'Trans' THEN 1
    WHEN type = 'Arriv' THEN 2
    WHEN type = 'Ofic'  THEN 3
    WHEN type = 'Lib'   THEN 4
    WHEN type = 'Ret'   THEN 5
    WHEN type = 'Desc'  THEN 6
    WHEN type = 'Dev'   THEN 7
    END) from milestone
    WHERE operation_id = 1)
```